# kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to get a info box working with Google Maps API. When trying to run the application, and adding a marker with custom info box it crashes.
Here is my code:

class MainMapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private val test: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

private var mLocationPermissionGranted: Boolean = false
private val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: Int = 1234
// ^Number isnt definitive, as long as its unique inside the application
private val DEFAULT_ZOOM: Float = 15.0F

private var mLastKnownLocation: Location? = null

private val mDefaultLocation = LatLng(60.312491, 24.484248)

private lateinit var mFusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient





override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_maps)


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
}


override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    getDeviceLocation()

    //PRESSING WILL ADD MARKER
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener { point ->
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert)
        } else {
            builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        }
        val marker = MarkerOptions().position(point)
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to add a map location here?")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to add a map location here?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    mMap.addMarker(marker)
                            //CUSTOM MARKER
                            .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.pinetree_foreground))
                })

                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    // do nothing
                })
                .show()

        true
       val mapInfoWindowFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.infoWindowMap) as MapInfoWindowFragment

        //Set Custom InfoWindow
         val infoWindow = InfoWindow(point, InfoWindow.MarkerSpecification(0, 0), mapInfoWindowFragment)
        // Shows the InfoWindow or hides it if it is already opened.
        mapInfoWindowFragment.infoWindowManager()?.toggle(infoWindow, true);


    })
```

And here is the error Logcat gives me:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.example.sampo.luontoalueet.MapInfoWindowFragment
    at com.example.sampo.luontoalueet.MainMapsActivity$onMapReady$1.onMapClick(MainMapsActivity.kt:123)
```

My question is how to change change this statement into non-null type?

```
val mapInfoWindowFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.infoWindowMap) as MapInfoWindowFragment
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `findfragmentById` is returning `null` (which indicates that your fragment does not exist).

If you're absolutely sure that fragment cannot be `null` at this point, you need to review your code. Maybe your fragment is not attached to `supportFragmentManager`?

If you want to handle a case where this fragment might not exist, You can use nullable cast `as?`:

```
val mapInfoWindowFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.infoWindowMap) as? MapInfoWindowFragment
```

Then you can check conditionally `if(mapInfoWindowFragment == null)` and handle the null case.